# Strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5

Tags: java, maven

I have a project which uses `Maven 3.2.1` and `Java 1.7`.

When I build this project using maven as `maven clean install` I see error as

```
 error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
```

The code where it complains is

```
        final String activeProfile = environment.getActiveProfiles()[0];
        switch (activeProfile) {
            case "integration":
                DataSetupTest.liquibaseUpdate(entityManager, true);
                break;
            case "default":
                DataSetupTest.liquibaseUpdate(entityManager, false);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException(activeProfile + " is not a recognized @Profile");
        }
```

I confirmed the versions for `maven` and `java` as

**maven**

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T09:37:52-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

**java**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for quick pointers. I do **not** use `source` or `target` in my `pom.xml` but I enforce that the java version to be `>=1.7` as

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[1.7,)</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Plus `JAVA_HOME` is correctly pointed to `1.7`

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Does your `pom.xml` have a `target` and/or `source` elements?

Comment: You might have the latest version of Java installed on your machine, but your project could be using a lower version. Check your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Maven uses Java 1.5 by default. And it's no rocket science to search this in the net before asking.

Comment: I updated question with my `pom.xml`

Comment: @daydreamer: **please** add `target` element in your pom as noted by Sotirios and explained in an answer in the duplicate Q/A.

Comment: Thanks! After adding `target` element, the error is gone. Thanks a lot for making me learn something new this morning!